# Graphical Layout Editor not DROPPING

Tags: java, android, eclipse

The layout editor itself is working fine, but it doesn't want DROP where I want it to drop.

It's only dropped in the very top left corner, and gravity doesn't change anything. If I drag it elsewhere, it just doesn't work.

It's the same anywhere, whether it's a different xml or just a new xml.

Is this an eclipse problem or a Java problem?

Thanks, and Happy New Year!

Comment: Nothing related to java, it's an Eclipse problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you come from an XCode or Visual Studio background? If so, yes, the "graphical layout editor" for Android is weird, as it depends chiefly on relative positioning of elements, unless you user AbsoluteLayout controls, which give you pixel-by-pixel positioning power.

This looks to be a good overview of the different kinds of layouts available in Android... the thing you have to remember about Eclipse and its ilk is that they assume you want to use certain layouts (Linear appears to be the default), to make it easier for you to create layouts that scale appropriately to size, irregardless of pixel density or resolution.

http://www.sitepoint.com/know-your-layouts-in-android/

Good luck!